# Is there a way to run one bash file which executes commands in local and server terminal also

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am running the bash files to make a Mongo dump on daily bases.But In local directory I am running a one bash file which connects to server terminal.And in server terminal I am running the other file which makes a Mongo dump.

But is it possible to make one file which connects to MongoDB server terminal and run the commands on the sever.

I tried with many commands but it was not possible to run the commands on the server terminal with one bash file, when the server terminal opens up then the left over commands does not execute.

Is it possible to do one bash file and execute the server commands on the server..?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your DB remotely using this command :

```
mongo --username username --password secretstuff --host YOURSERVERIP --port 28015
```

You can then automate this by including your pertaining commands ( including the above ) in a bash script that you can run from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above problem, answer from Matias Barrios seems to be correct for me. You don't use a script on the server, but use tools on your local machine that connect to the server services and manage them.

Nevertheless, to execute a script on a distant server, you could use ssh. This is not the right solution in your case, but answer the question in your title.

```
ssh myuser@MongoServer ./script.sh param1
```

This can be used in a local script and execute script.sh on the server MongoServer (with param1 and) with system privileges of the user myuser.

Beforehand, don't forget to avoid password request with

```
ssh-copy-id myuser@MongoServer
```

This will copy your ssh public key in the myuser directory of the MongoServer